# React / Typescript "Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, tslint

I know this Typescript error has been asked about many times but I haven't been able to find an answer that makes sense to me in my situation.

```
import * as React from 'react';

type OnboardContext = {
 isRunning: boolean;
 run(): void;
 stop(): void;
};

const OnboardContext = React.createContext<OnboardContext>({
 isRunning: false,
 run: () => {},
 stop: () => {}
});
```

`Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.`

I also get the same error in the case below

`const [step, setStep] = React.useState<number>(1);`

How would I remove the error for these cases without removing the typing?

Here if my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "build",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/*"]
    },
    "strict": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a TSLint error and not a TypeScript error? It looks like a TypeScript error to me. I am wondering about your TypeScript configuration. Also, how are you importing `React` into your file?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin thanks, I added more information to the question including my tsconfig and my import statement for react.

Comment: Also, you're right about it being a ts error so I changed that.